# mysql slow complex query with order by

Tags: mysql, join, percona

The below query even without the `order by` is very slow and I can't figure out why. I'm guessing it's the `where date_affidavit_file` but how can I make it fast with that `order by`as well? Perhaps a sublect on the job_id's that match the where and then pass that into the rest of the code but I still need to order by server the servername like this. Any suggestions?

```
explain select sql_no_cache court_county, job.id as jid, job_status,
    DATE_FORMAT(job.datetime_served, '%m/%d/%Y') as dserved , 
    CONCAT(server.namefirst, ' ', server.namelast) as servername, client_name,
    DATE_FORMAT(job.datetime_received, '%m/%d/%Y') as dtrec ,
    DATE_FORMAT(job.datetime_give2server, '%m/%d/%Y') as dtg2s, 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_kase_filed, '%m/%d/%Y') as dkf, 
    DATE_FORMAT(job.date_sent_to_court, '%m/%d/%Y') as dtstc ,
    TO_DAYS(datetime_served )-TO_DAYS(date_kase_filed) as totaldays from job
    left join kase on kase.id=job.kase_id 
    left join server on job.server_id=server.id
    left join client on kase.client_id=client.id
    left join LUcourt on LUcourt.id=kase.court_id 
    where date_affidavit_filed  is not null and date_affidavit_filed  !='' order by servername;
```

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------+----------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys        | key     | key_len | ref                   | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+----------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | job     | ALL    | date_affidavit_filed | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                  | 365212 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | kase    | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY | 4       | pserve.job.kase_id    |      1 |                                              | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | server  | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY | 4       | pserve.job.server_id  |      1 |                                              | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | client  | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY | 4       | pserve.kase.client_id |      1 |                                              | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | LUcourt | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY | 4       | pserve.kase.court_id  |      1 |                                              | 
+----+-------------+---------+--------+----------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your tables?

Comment: This might be a question for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: You are using left joins. Do you expect any `null` values?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have indexes on the following columns. `job.kase_id` or `job.server_id`

Also you are ordering by a calculated field which is not optimal.  Perhaps order by a field with index.

If you need to preserve that exact sort, you might want to add a field in the DB for that value. And populate it with appropriate values or set up a trigger on the DB to populate it for you automatically.

Comment: The `Using filesort` is likely the bit that is slowing it down to heck - I am just unable to say why (and it isn't always related to a simple index).

Answer (score 1):

This can speed up the order by:

```
CREATE INDEX namefull ON server (namefirst,namelast);
```

if you do `ORDER BY (server.namefirst, server.namelast)` instead of `ORDER BY servername`, which should produce the same output.

You can also create indexes on each table on any field you are left joining, that can improve the performance of your query too.

Answer (score 0):

When you write,

```
where date_affidavit_filed  is not null and date_affidavit_filed  !=''
```

you practically are selecting most of the rows. Or at least so many that it is not worthwhile to run through the indexing. The query planner sees that there *is* an index involving `date_affidavit_filed`, but decides not to use it and go with the WHERE clause, which only involves `date_affidavit_filed`; so we know it's not a key issue, it must be a cardinality issue.

```
|  1 | SIMPLE      | job     | ALL    | date_affidavit_filed | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                  | 365212 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
```

You can try optimizing this by creating an index on

```
date_affidavit_filed, kase_id, server_id
```

in that order. How many rows are returned by the query?

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting everything that isn't empty really.
That really means everything.
I don't know how many rows of data you have have but it's a lot to go through.

Try narrowing your query to a date range or specific client.

If you really need everything, don't output it one row after a time, but build up a big string in the software you use to output with all formatting, and then when you're finished looping through the results and you have constructed the data you wish to output you can output them in one big go.

You could also use paging.
Just add `limit 0,30` on page 1, `limit 30,30` on page two, etc.. and let the end user walk through the pages.